# Why the Device with "CPU" name is not registered in the InferenceEngine when using openvino?

Tags: openvino

**Description:**

I have completed the installation of openvino toolkit and build the samples provided in deployment_tool/open_model_zoo/demos, then when I run the ./segmentation_demo, I got the problem like this. Does anyone used to got the same pro as me? Thanks for your stay.

**on my machine:**

(base) [root@VM-218-78-centos ~/omz_demos_build/intel64/Release]# ./segmentation_demo -i 0 -m /data/chriisyang/fastseg-small/fastseg-small_t15_108.xml

[ INFO ] InferenceEngine: 0x7efdd1f31090

[ INFO ] Parsing input parameters

[ INFO ] Device info

***[ ERROR ] Device with "CPU" name is not registered in the InferenceEngine***

Answer (score 1):

I have validated the Segmentation Demo using OpenVINO2021.3 and everything works fine. Make sure you meet the [System Requirements](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_linux.html#system_requirements) needed.